# How should I attach a picture in Limesurvey for the email template?

Tags: limesurvey

When I try to attach a picture in Limesurvey v.1.87+ in the email template, it is attached correctly (it seems because I can see it) but when I send the invitation to the tokens, the picture does not appear in the email at all and I can´t figure out why.

Has somebody the same problem before?

Thank you very much to you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put complete link of the picture,

Replace

```
<img src="upload/surveys/sid/images/pic.png" />
```

by

```
<img src="http://example.org/limesurvey/upload/surveys/sid/images/pic.png" />
```

LS 1.87 don't support attachment. And the link or not email ready (fixed in 2.0).

Comment: With 2.50 version and https://github.com/SondagesPro/LimeSurvey-SondagesPro : if you use /upload/surveys/sid/images/pic.png for source : image/picture is send with/in the mail.